# NGINX reverse proxy / php pre processing

Tags: php, apache, nginx, proxy, reverse-proxy

I would somehow solve the following scenario: We have a server nginx acting as a reverse proxy for some apache servers. We should make sure that when a request comes to nginx proxy it is pre processed by a php script that sets some HTTP request headers, based on the URL content, and then the URL is passed to the server apache. 
We should avoid redirects in this process, but I have no idea how I could do it.

Thanks a lot...

[EDIT]
Sorry for the vague question. Our setup is as follows: nginx is used as a balancer for some apache web server. On the web server runs an application that generates the content of e-commerce (and page categories) on the basis of the analysis of the submitted URL. We use a third-party analysis tool that requires a request header valorized with category but the categories are calculated by the php code of the application... I should make that the request processed by nginx will have an header before arriving to apache. I can extract the code from the php application and create an intermediate layer but I have no idea how to manage the whole process.
This is a simple draw: Black as-is, in green to-be (or may be-to-be)
[simple solution draw](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O4mZd.png)

Comment: You could (ab)use auth_request module for this

Answer (score 0):

Your question is very vague - and will probably be closed on that basis. My response here is intended as a comment - but its a bit long for the comment box.

That you are using nginx as a reverse proxy implies that you are somewhat concerned with performance. While it would be quite possible to implement what you describe, the nature of PHP running in a webserver means that it will be rather inefficient at the task you describe - each incoming web request will require a new connection to the backend webserver.

Presumably there is some application running on or behind the apache webservers - is there a reason you don't implement the required functionality there?

Can you provide examples of the changes you need to apply to requests and responses? It's possible that some of this could be handled by nginx or apache.

Alternatively you might have a look at ICAP (rfc3507) which is protocol designed for supporting these kind of transformations. Although there sre server implementations using PHP, I suspect they will have most of the same performance issues referenced above.